# volatile pointer to volatile data

Tags: c++, volatile, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to evaluate different version of my program to see how fast they are. I found out a weird thing in Visual Studio 2010 (using windows 10). I have not tried it yet on different compilers or systems. See the code below:

```
uint64 t=0x45484856167;
int k=0;
(volatile) uint64* (volatile) source=new uint64[2048];
source[0]=0x74451523156321;
for (int k=1;k<1024;k++) {source[k]=(source[k-1]<<14)+713*k}//initilisation
uint64 start = Gettime();
//main loop
for (uint64 i = 0; i < 900000000;i+=1) {
    const uint64 mask=source[k+1];
    ((t&mask)==(source[k]&mask))? k=(k+2)&2047 : k=(k-2)&2047 ;
}
//main loop end
uint64 end = Gettime();
```

Now, when both volatiles were used, it has the same running time as in the case where none was used. Same happened when just the second volatile is used. But when only the first one is used, it slows down. However, deleting the initialization loop or putting some more code between the initialization and the for second for loop, removes this phenomenon and any combination of volatiles have the same running time. I get why those two modifications might cause speeding up the main loop in case of volatile data, but why is the `volatile * volatile` faster than `volatile *`?

Comment: Looks like you really should examine the generated assembly code.

Comment: Before I put any effort into this why are you using `volatile` in modern C++ code?

Comment: Consider adding `volatile` and `visual-studio-2010` tags

Comment: @RichardCritten Hardware-related programming isn't modern?

Comment: @RichardCritten: `volatile` is not obsolete.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I never said it was, but it's use in standard C++ is now limited to the case(s) where you have you have hardware or signal handlers updating a volatile variable, or you need access to hardware registers.

Comment: @RichardCritten: To _some_ degree, it always was. ;) Regardless, given the content of the OP's code, I think we can rule out the [mis-]use of `volatile` for protection in `std::thread`s.

Comment: I wanted to be sure that every access to the array is loading from memory, not just moving a register, I dont know well assemlby code, so I wanted to avoid for sure the possibility, that some optimisation causes repeated access to the same index be done by moving registers. But I put it at wrong position at first, after realising my mistake, I corrected it. Then I tried to put both, just becuase I was wondering and there went my surprise.